# How to set layout property from code

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-relativelayout, parameters

How can I set the property of an TextView which comes under a RelativeLayout from the code.

Here s my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/team_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag_left"     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_left"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"  
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I set the properties like "android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag_left" for the textview from the code.

Comment: How do you access that layout? Is it the layout you are setting as your content view or do you inflate it using an inflater?

Comment: The layout is set on activity oncreate. I m setting the layout as the content view

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for the textview and then use [addRule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29).

Example:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LAYOUT_ABOVE, R.id.flag_left);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.addRule(android.R.attr.layout_above, R.id.flag_left);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this.

Comment: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 1); Its not working as expected. Am I doing anything wrong!?

Comment: `RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL` will not work. You need to use `android.R.attr.layout_centerVertical` For more valuse look into this table http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html